# stretched div height using Jquery Mobile version issue

Tags: jquery

i am using the jquery for stretching the `Div` Height from parent `DIV` all going Good, but when i got to see from mobile then height still showing as stretch,  any jquery code have to solve this issue? i am using this Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var parentHeight = $(".logo-col").parent().height();
   $(".clientes-sidebar").height(parentHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your Code : 
Once the browser window is resized this will break, whereas the CSS ones will still work Like This :

```css
div#container {
    padding:20px;
    background:#F1F1F1
}
.content {
    width:150px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.text {
    font-family: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#555;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Title 1</h1>

        <div class="text">Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.
            <br>Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.
            <br>Sample Text.
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Title 2</h1>

        <div class="text">Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So Prefer To Use CSS :

Comment: is it work in all browsers? and bootstrap? with mobile version?

Comment: I think soo, it will work..... but you can also use media query for responsive      if not work.. I will Not tested in all browser.

Comment: this is CSS suggestion,  if you have jQuery suggestion will tel me thanks.